# Вопрос по поводу Resource Qualifier(xamarin)?

Tags: android, xamarin

Привет. Создал пустое Android приложение(через xamarin). В Resource Qualifier(UI Mode) есть несколько режимов отображения: Normal, Car Dock, Desk Dock, Television, Appliance, Watch. Что-бы убрать панель, выделенную, на фото нужно выбрать Watch. Но я делаю приложение под обычный Andorid девайс. Возможно ли в режиме Normal убрать эту панель? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все. Разобрался благодаря этой статье - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/